# Binning x axis data for a line graph

Tags: r

I have data on patient visits. Patients were seen at 8-week intervals until 40 weeks. The data contains the specific amount of weeks for each participant, e.g. 7.23478 weeks or 9.4324 weeks. However, I want my line graph to show one point for each visit for each treatment group for the measure on my y-axis (i.e. what is the y-axis value for treatment x at the 8-week visit, on average, not at 7.8 and 8.1 and 8.2 weeks on average).

Thanks in advance!

```
> dataset2
      X id   treatment     age    week   logCD4    sex      bins week_int
1     1  1      zA225z 36.4271  0.0000 3.135494   Male (-0.04,8]     <NA>
2     2  1      zA225z 36.4271  7.5714 3.044522   Male (-0.04,8]  8 weeks
3     3  1      zA225z 36.4271 15.5714 2.772589   Male    (8,16] 16 weeks
4     4  1      zA225z 36.4271 23.5714 2.833213   Male   (16,24] 24 weeks
5     5  1      zA225z 36.4271 32.5714 3.218876   Male   (32,40] 40 weeks
6     6  1      zA225z 36.4271 40.0000 3.044522   Male   (32,40] 40 weeks
7     7  2 zA400dA400n 47.8467  0.0000 3.068053   Male (-0.04,8]     <NA>
8     8  2 zA400dA400n 47.8467  8.0000 3.891820   Male (-0.04,8]  8 weeks
9     9  2 zA400dA400n 47.8467 16.0000 3.970292   Male    (8,16] 16 weeks
10   10  2 zA400dA400n 47.8467 23.0000 3.610918   Male   (16,24] 24 weeks
11   11  2 zA400dA400n 47.8467 30.7143 3.332205   Male   (24,32] 32 weeks
12   12  2 zA400dA400n 47.8467 39.0000 3.091042   Male   (32,40] 40 weeks
13   13  3      zX400d 60.2875  0.0000 3.737670   Male (-0.04,8]     <NA>

ggplot(dataset2,
  aes(x=week,y=logcd4, col=treatment)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=week, y=logcd4)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=week, y=logcd4))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(dataset2)` with enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to copy the data to test and verify solutions.

Comment: Post the output of `dput(dataset2`.

Comment: Sorry I can't - it's too large!

Comment: OK then use `dput(head(dataset2, 30))` or `dput(sample(dataset2, 30))` with n (I've guessed 30) so that it is representative of the data and the problem.

Comment: Are the values you're trying to plot along the x-axis the same as those in `week_int`, or do you want to plot by the `bins`?